# Why does Chromium handle touch differently than Firefox in my CentOS 8 system?

Tags: chromium, touchscreen

I have a CentOS 8 system and I've installed both Chromium and Firefox.
The computer is a Cybermed NB22 and the touch screen identifies itself as 'eTurboTouch Technology Inc. Cybernet 215 SP14014 Touch Panel'.

When I use Firefox (and everything else I've played with), pressing on the touch screen acts exactly like pressing the left mouse button in every way (you can select text, clicks work normally, etc).

When I use Chromium (which identifies as version 88.0.4324.150), if you tap on the open web page, it's fine. If you press and hold for a short time, it interprets the press as a right-click (you get an appropriate pop-up menu for the element you're touching). This seems to happen with any web page.

Is there some way to get Chromium to act like every other program on the system?

Answer (score 0):

You can block the context-menu action of Chrome by using the extension
[Context Menu Blocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/context-menu-blocker/hibfjefoddeenakbenbegknbhfhndjbj).

However, I doubt that you can force Chrome to change its handling of touch screens
any more than that.

Comment: So far that's what I've found - short of grabbing the source and modifying chromium, I'm not clear that I can have what I want.